# htaccess change subfolder root with subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a website *example.com* with this structure:

```
public_html/
    .htaccess
    index.php
    project/
        .htaccess
        public/
            index.php
```

the content of **public_html/.htaccess** is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

the content of **public_html/project/.htaccess** is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^public/ /public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

### Actual Result

I'm able to see **public_html/index.php** when url is **example.com**

I'm not able to see **public_html/project/public/index.php** when url is **example.com/project**. **Error 404**

### Expected Result

I want to be able to see **public_html/index.php** when url is **example.com**

and i want to see **public_html/project/public/index.php** when url is **example.com/project**

### Additionl info

If I put the code from **public_html/project/.htaccess** to the root's htaccess file, it works.

example:

```
public_html/
    .htaccess
    index.php
    project/
        index.php
```

[**public_html/.htaccess**]

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule !^project/ /project%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

If the url is **example.com** I'm able to see **public_html/project/index.php**

Comment: It should be: `RewriteRule !^public/ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]`

Comment: This not working on subdir. I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content of `public_html/.htaccess` should be:

```bash
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Content of `public_html/project/.htaccess` should be:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^public/ public/index.php [L,NC]
```

Make sure to test it from a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: Sorry but this not working. I tried on a new browser and on a new device too. Always 404 error

Comment: The url I entered in the browser is: https://www.example.com/project and I was redirected to https://www.example.com/project/ with error 404.
I have no more rules in my htaccess files, the code is exactly copy pasted from your answer. The only difference is example.com to my real domain

Comment: I'm on a shared hosting, is it possible that apache is configured to block overwriting?
Something like AllowOverride, or has it nothing to do with it?

Comment: The URL I entered in the browser is ```https://www.example.com/project/``` and returns 404.
```https://www.example.com/project/public/``` work fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246960/discussion-between-francesco-mineo-and-anubhava).

Comment: Now ```https://www.example.com/project/``` shows ```public_html/project/index.php``` and ```https://www.example.com/project/public/``` shows ```pubilc_html/project/public/index.php```. Not as expected

Comment: ok another update to answer. I have joined chat link but probably you've already left that tab

Comment: @anubhava, Thanks for sharing nice code sir. Could you please do let us know why `DirectoryIndex` for index.php in base directory? Since its being already handled in inner level .htaccess. Will be grateful if you could explain. Also 2nd question: can't we use non-existing pages RewriteRules to index.php in 1st htaccess rather than `DirectoryIndex`. Thank you sir.

Comment: `DirectoryIndex` probably isn't needed if set already in Apache config. Just in case it is not there already here it is making sure to render `index.php` from site root directory for `example.com/` URL